# Plugman installs to platform_www and NOT to www as it used to in Cordova 6.1

Tags: android, ios, cordova, plugman

I have an app built with an older version of Cordova, 3.x . Which I now want to upgrade to Cordova 6.1 . For Android using platform specific workflow.

When I created that one, I used cordova cli first, then added plugins with plugman and kept working from that moment on, using the platform specific workflow. This is because I need to add customizations to AndroidManifest.xml, for example, and I don't find how to do it if I use the CLI.

Today I upgraded cordova, and regenerated my project from scratch. When I try to install the plugins using plugman, it installs to platform_www folder instead of www folder. Since I am using platform-specific workflow, this doesn't work. I tried using the -www parameter in plugman, but apparently that was ignored since it kept installing to platform_www folder.

This is how I tried:

```
plugman install --platform android --project platforms/android --plugin cordova-plugin-console --www platforms/android/assets/www
```

Since I didn't find a way for plugman to work as it had worked before in older versions, I tried installing cordova-android to create the project with it. So maybe then plugman will work as desired.

I did:

```
npm install -g cordova-android
```

But afterwards when I run cordova-android in the command prompt, it says command not recognized. It recognizes cordova ok, but not cordova-android.

Can anyone help me please? I need to either:

a) know if there is a way to make any customization to AndroidManifest.xml when using the CLI (and Info.plist when working on iOS)

b) know how to make plugman install the plugins to assets/www instead of platform_www folder

c) know how to make cordova-android run

I have plugman version 1.2.1 and cordova version 6.1.1, I updated both today to latest.

Thanks for any help!